# Threads running simultaneously from the same object

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a java program, where i have one Even object, that has a next method, where it is incrementing a value twice:

```
public class Even
{
  private int n = 0;
  public int next()
  {
    n++;
    n++;
    return n;
  }
}
```

if I run two threads, from the main method, where I access the same object, it ALWAYS returns even. Since both threads are accessing the same objects, should it not return an uneven value at some point?

```
Even even = new Even();
    Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            System.out.println(even.next());
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("even");
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    System.out.println("fail");
                    Logger.getLogger(Exercise2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    return;
                }

            }

        }

    });
    Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            System.out.println(even.next());
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("even");
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    System.out.println("fail");
                    Logger.getLogger(Exercise2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    });
    t1.start();
    t2.start();

   }
}
```

Can anyone clarify my confusion?

Comment: Theoretically they could return an uneven value but it might be hard to reproduce what you want because calling `n++` is so fast that the threads barely have time to chime in and read `n` between the two calls to `n++`.

Comment: Not to mention that both threads could be seeing their own value for `n`, since it's not `volatile`. Basically you have broken multithreaded code, so you can't expect anything to happen for certain.

Comment: What Would happen if i declared my n variable as volatile?